# How to make the new Firebase Crashlytics work with Android Studio 4 "Apply Changes"?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Ever since I updated from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics, the "Apply Changes and Restart Activity" option fails with the following message:

```
Changes were not applied.
Modifications to AndroidManifest.xml require an app restart.
Manifest 'AndroidManifest.xml' was modified.
```

Also, whenever I try to rerun the app using the "Run app", the following exception is thrown at startup:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firebasetest, PID: 11320
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:122)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics.init(FirebaseCrashlytics.java:165)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar.buildCrashlytics(CrashlyticsRegistrar.java:55)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar.access$lambda$0(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar$$Lambda$1.create(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:69)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:158)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:563)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:304)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:268)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:253)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Running the app again works normally.

To upgrade I've followed the instructions from [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android) link, except I didn't add the Google Analytics SDK. I've since tried to include it, but the problem persists.

I've also removed the Crashlytics specific build files `ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId` and `ext.enableCrashlytics`.

Here are the relevant excerpts from the gradle files:

**Project-level build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you add the json file to your app folder in your project ?

Comment: @takieddine Yes, the file is there. When the exception is not thrown, everything works fine.

Comment: Seems like the crashlytics are well implemented , because i never worked with fabric anyway , so no idea , sorry

Comment: can you show your manifest file ?

Comment: @takieddine unfortunately no, but I didn't change anything on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just upgrade

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```